# How to block a request which does not has a header using Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

My application back-end was laid on AWS Lambda and exposing API's using API Gateway. And forntend on CloudFront. I want to block a request which does not has a header using AWS service. Can anyone suggest me which AWS service will helpful to do this and what is the process?

Answer (score 0):

Please, go to `API Gateway` -> `APIs` (select the Api) -> `Resources` (Select your resource) -> `Select Method Request block` -> `HTTP Request Headers` -> `add your custom header` and make it **required**.

See the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmefj.jpg)